# Vuetify how to override styles correctly?

Tags: vuetify.js

I’m making a search input based on v-text-field, trying to integrate select into this input. To select v-select, I use v-slot:prepend.

But with all the options, I absolutely cannot override the styles of vuetify components. I need to remove the frames from the input and make a common frame for these two components.

The problem is that I can't even catch them in the inspector. No matter what he wrote everything to the left.

```
box-shadow: none!important;
border: 0!important;
```

Not working on all tags vuetify component.

Comment: What is the code for your v-select? It would be helpful to see how your v-slot is coded as well as other options/props you're using.  An image here would also be helpful to make things clear.  There are many built-in styles possible with v-select so it's not obvious what your v-select currently looks like or how your specific v-select should be modified to meet your requirement.  Also, what CSS selector did you try? It's just as important to use the correct selector as it is to change the correct properties, and you've not shown this.